# Echarts: How to order Stack bar chart by xaxis group

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visualization, echarts

[image: 1]

The biggest segment of the bar should be at the bottom.

Is there any charting library in js/react that allows doing this?

I am using #echarts in my project. Couldn't find any option to configure this. There is also an open issue on github here https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/18271.

I am open to change the charting library as long as it is open sourced.

Comment: I believe you can just sort your input data the way you want and apply it in chart.

Comment: I can't do that since, on echart - I either need to define a series or dataset. And stacking is configured by an identifier `stack: string`. I have multiple series stacked together, hence sorting on the series will have no impact.

Comment: xAxis: ['jan', 'feb', 'march'],
series: [ {name: 'series 1`, data: [2, 11, 32], stack: 'all'} ,   {name: 'series 2`, data: [12, 1, 8], stack: 'all'}, {name: 'series 3`, data: [8, 12, 9], stack: 'all'}]

This is how the data looks. 
I want segments on each individual bar to be sorted by value. @CodeThing

Answer (score 1):

We can do something like this in HighChart.

```
function load() {
  function label() {
    return (this.point.high - this.point.low).toString()
  }

  function tooltip() {
    return this.key + ': ' + (this.point.high - this.point.low)
  }

  const allSeries = this.options.series
  const colors = this.options.colors
  const stackingMatrix = []

  allSeries.forEach((series, sIndex) => {
    series.data.forEach((point, pIndex) => {
      if (!stackingMatrix[pIndex]) {
        stackingMatrix[pIndex] = []
      }

      stackingMatrix[pIndex].push({
        series: sIndex,
        y: point
      })
    })
  })

  const stackData = []

  stackingMatrix.forEach((stack, index) => {
    let stackY = 0

    stack = stackingMatrix[index].sort((dataL, dataS) => {
      return dataS.y < dataL.y ? -1 : dataS.y > dataL.y ? 1 : 0
    })

    stack.forEach((point) => {
      stackData.push({
        color: colors[point.series],
        low: stackY,
        high: stackY + point.y,
        name: allSeries[point.series].name,
        x: index
      })
      
      stackY += point.y
    })
  })

  this.update({
    tooltip: {
      formatter: tooltip
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'columnrange',
        data: stackData
      },
      {
        data: []
      },
      {
        data: []
      }
    ]
  })
}

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    height: 379,
    events: {
      load
    },
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Arsenal', 'Chelsea', 'Liverpool', 'Manchester United']
  },
  yAxis: {
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: false,
      align: 'center'
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      cursor: 'pointer',
      groupPadding: 0,
    }
  },
  series: [{
      'name': 'BPL',
      'data': [4, 1, 5, 4]
    },
    {
      'name': 'FA Cup',
      'data': [2, 3, 0, 1]
    },
    {
      'name': 'CL',
      'data': [1, 2, 1, 2]
    }
  ]
});
```

Check this in fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/codething/6oy23wje/

Comment: This is a column chart. This works, but label/legend/tooltips are messed up.